# Windows 8.1 is asking for a password instead of PIN to login

Tags: windows-8.1

I restarted my Windows 8.1 notebook into safe mode, and now I need to login with a password.

Normally I login with my pin number. I don't remember setting up a password, but it won't accept an empty one.

update: I configured booting into safe mode with the program `msconfig`, so now it probably always starts in safe mode. Is there a way to change this into normal mode?

1. I want to boot into normal mode
2. I want Win 8.1 is ask for a PIN instead of password at logon

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot setup a pin, to access your account in Windows 8.1, unless you also have setup a password.  The pin only works to access that account, normally an account linked to a Microsoft Account, on that specific device.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you've selected `Normal Startup`, or at least `Selective Startup` with System Services enabled in `msconfig`

[image]

And make sure you uncheck `Safe boot`

[image]

Once you're booting in `Normal Startup`, the service that handles PIN login will be re-enabled (only password is available in Safe Mode or Diagnostic Mode).

After that, login using your PIN once (clicking the icon below), it will then default to PIN from then onwards.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I can't login (because I forgot the password), so also not start msconfig...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, setting up Windows for the first time requires you to connect an E-Mail-Address of yours, which now means you need to **fill in your password of that E-Mail-Address**.

**EDIT**: On the login screen, there should be an icon for **Sign-in-Options**, probably at the right bottom of the screen. There you can switch between Password and PIN to log in.

After that, when Windows is booted in *safe-mode*,

1. press **Windows-Key + R** (or open the **Run Dialog** from the Windows Start Menu)
2. type **msconfig** and press **OK**.
3. Now **System Configuration Utility** should open up.
4. Go to the **General**-Tab and check **Normal Start-Up**.
5. Go to the **Boot**-Tab and uncheck **Safe Boot**.
6. Press **OK** and restart.

Comment: "setting up Windows for the first time requires you to connect an E-Mail-Address of yours" - It is not actually required.  You can create a local account that is NOT linked to a Microsoft Account in Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.